# Dependency injection for Dialog classes

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

Should dependency injection be used for the dialog class?
For example, is this code principled?
How about Intent, Navigate, Binding and...?

```
@Module
@InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
object FragmentModule {
    @FragmentScoped
    @Provides
    fun provideDialog()=
     SampleDialog()
}
```